# Autofac: How to use per request dependency in the SingleInstance scope?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

There are `IDbConnection` connection dependency registered as `per-request` and `ApplicationOAuthProvider` registered as `single instance`.

```
builder.Register(c => new SqlConnection(WebConfigUtils.DefaultConnectionString))
            .As<IDbConnection>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterType<ApplicationOAuthProvider>()
            .As<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>()
            .PropertiesAutowired()
            .SingleInstance();
```

Need to store user permissions in the identity claims. For this purpose I have created command GetRolePermissions, and in this command I want to inject `IDbConnection` instance.

```
public class GetRolePermissions
{
    public class Command: IRequest<List<string>>
    {
        public ICollection<AspNetUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Handler : AsyncRequestHandler<Command, List<string>>
    {
        private IDbConnection databaseConnection;

        public Handler(IDbConnection databaseConnection)
        {
            this.databaseConnection = databaseConnection;
        }
    }
}
```

This command is being created in the `ApplicationOAuthProvider`

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(AspNetUser user, string authenticationType)
    {
        user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var identity = await mediator.Send(new GenerateUserIdentity.Command
        {
            AuthenticationType = authenticationType,
            User = user
        });

        List<string> permissions = null;
        permissions = await mediator.Send(new GetRolePermissions.Command { UserRoles = user.Roles });
        var permissionClaimValue = permissions != null && permissions.Count > 0
            ? permissions.Aggregate((resultString, permission) => resultString + "," + permission)
            : "";
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(AuthenticationConstants.Gender, user.Gender.ToString()));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(AuthenticationConstants.Permissions, permissionClaimValue));
        return identity;
    }
}
```

`permissions = await mediator.Send(new GetRolePermissions.Command { UserRoles = user.Roles });` - throws an error as `GetRolePermissions.Handler` need to inject `IDbConnection`, but current autofac scope of `ApplicationOAuthProvider` is `"root"` and there is no `iDbConnection` registered in this scope. But it exists in the `per-request` scope.

Don't want to use `perLifettime` for IDbConnection, because I think, that `dbConnection` should be closed when it is unneccessary. I was think to do smth like this:

```
using(var scope = AutofacConfig.container.BeginLifiTime("AutofacWebRequest")) 
{
      permissions = await mediator.Send(new GetRolePermissions.Command { UserRoles = user.Roles });
}
```

but can't make this solution working. And I don't know how to get the container properly, for now it static variable of AutofacConfig, that I set manually.

How to enable injection of `IDbConnection` into this `GetPermissions.Handler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `InstancePerLifetimeScope()` is the solution that you look for. All you need to do is to inject DbConnection **factory** that produces owned ([docs link 1](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-owned) and [docs link 2](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html#owned-instances)) instances of DbConnection rather then DbConnection itself.

```
// registration

builder.RegisterType<SqlConnection>()
    .As<IDbConnection>()
    .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("connectionString", WebConfigUtils.DefaultConnectionString))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

// usage

public class GetRolePermissions
{
    public class Command: IRequest<List<string>>
    {
        public ICollection<AspNetUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class Handler : AsyncRequestHandler<Command, List<string>>
    {
        private Func<Owned<IDbConnection>> _connectionFactory;

        public Handler(Func<Owned<IDbConnection>> connectionFactory)
        {
            _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        }

        // not really sure where your consuming code is, so just something off the top of my head
        public DontKnowYourResultType Handle(GetRolePermissions.Command cmd) {
            using (var ownedConnection = _connectionFactory()) {
                // ownedConnection.Value is the DbConnection you want
                // ... do your stuff with that connection
            } // and connection gets destroyed upon leaving "using" scope
        }
    }
}
```

It does change behavior for the scopes that are children of request scope, but I'm not sure if it's a problem for your code or not - just give it a try, chances are that it should work fine. If not then you know where to ask. ;)

Comment: Thanks, after this asnwer I will read more docs and implement more examples for better understading of autofac and DI in common.